# child File associations in alfresco

Tags: alfresco

I am using webscripts to create content on alfresco and now I want to associate some already created content as child associations to the parent content.

How can i register contents as child associations to another content in webscripts?

Comment: Are you using your own webscripts, or built in ones? i.e. do you want to know how to create an association in JavaScript for inside your own webscript, or do you want a REST API call to do it for you?

Comment: @Gagravarr: I am writing my own Java based webscript to do this task and want to add peer associations to a content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no knowledge of existing web scripts that allow handling multiple-parents relationships, even if there might be some (CMIS?). In case you're developing your custom web script, then you can use the following Java API:

```
ChildAssociationRef ref =  nodeService.addChild(destinationParent, 
                                                childNode,
                                                ContentModel.ASSOC_CONTAINS,
                                                destinationAssocQName);
```

which translated into the following Javascript:

```
destinationParent.addNode(childNode);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply!, Is there any way to add peer association via JAVA api? Just realized that child association will not be apt for my case.

Comment: Peer associations are available through the [`NodeService.createAssociation`](http://dev.alfresco.com/resource/docs/java/repository/org/alfresco/service/cmr/repository/NodeService.html#createAssociation)

Comment: I tried this but I am getting below error : 'Association: Association[ class=ClassDef[name={http://www.alfresco.org/model/content/1.0}folder], name={http://www.alfresco.org/model/content/1.0}contains, target class={http://www.alfresco.org/model/system/1.0}base, source role=null, target role=null]
   Required Source Type: {http://www.alfresco.org/model/content/1.0}folder', It seems that association can only be done on folder and not on content/file, is that so?

Comment: Associations are part of the content model, where you specify target and source types. Yes, the [`ASSOC_CONTAINS`](http://dev.alfresco.com/resource/docs/java/repository/org/alfresco/model/ContentModel.html#ASSOC_CONTAINS) requires a `cm:folder` as a source, while e.g. [`ASSOC_CHILDREN`](http://dev.alfresco.com/resource/docs/java/repository/org/alfresco/model/ContentModel.html#ASSOC_CHILDREN) needs a `sys:container`. If peer associations is what you're after, you might need to create some custom ones yourself.

Comment: it worked fine when I created and associated two dm: contents(I also created my custom association). But it is giving issue while I am trying to associate two wcm: contents, The error that I am getting is : 17:40:40,477  ERROR [extensions.webscripts.AbstractRuntime] Exception from executeScript - redirecting to status template error: AVM does not support arbitrary associations.
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: AVM does not support arbitrary

Comment: That's a limitation of the AVM repository implementation, used to store content for the old Alfresco WCM. If you're starting a new project, I would strongly recommend you to move to the [new implementation](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Web_Quick_Start) available since alfresco 3.4.0, which makes use of the ADM ("standard") alfresco repository implementation, where such surprises will not show up.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your valuable comments!!